# A Decimal String Style of Datestamp from an Airtable to a Correct and True DateStamp in a Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In Airtable the DateTime Data is correct but if you upload it in the Big Query, it will transform into a Decimal String Style of Numbers.  See the table below:

| Date | True Date |
| --- | --- |
| 44493.61666667 | 2021-10-24T14:48:00 |
| 44522.775 | 2021-11-22T18:36:00 |
| 44493.67916666667 | 2021-10-24T16:18:00 |
| 44522.739583333336 | 2021-11-22T17:45:00 |

This is the problem I have encountered. Assuming the table name is Airtable.  Can you give a suggested query to convert it into the correct and true timestamp?
Actually, I post it also [on my blog](https://www.theaccountingtactics.com/2021/12/BigQueryBQ-DateProblems-DateSituations-that-are-Hard-to-Analyze-and-Takes-Time-ToCrack%20.html). Thank you for your suggested answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to BigQuery -
but I found out that your `"Date"` value is a division seconds to days (seconds / 86400) since `TIMESTAMP '1899-12-30 00:00:00'` :

```
WITH
airtable(date,true_date) AS (
          SELECT 44493.61666666667 ,TIMESTAMP '2021-10-24T14:48:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 44522.775         ,TIMESTAMP '2021-11-22T18:36:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 44493.67916666667 ,TIMESTAMP '2021-10-24T16:18:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 44522.739583333336,TIMESTAMP '2021-11-22T17:45:00'
)
SELECT
  *
, true_date - "date" AS anchor_ts
, CAST (("date" * 86400) AS INTEGER) AS secs_snc_anchor
FROM airtable;
-- out         date        |      true_date      |      anchor_ts      | secs_snc_anchor 
-- out --------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------
-- out  44493.616666666670 | 2021-10-24 14:48:00 | 1899-12-30 00:00:00 |      3844248480
-- out  44522.775000000000 | 2021-11-22 18:36:00 | 1899-12-30 00:00:00 |      3846767760
-- out  44493.679166666670 | 2021-10-24 16:18:00 | 1899-12-30 00:00:00 |      3844253880
-- out  44522.739583333336 | 2021-11-22 17:45:00 | 1899-12-30 00:00:00 |      3846764700
```

So you could add your `"Date"` value to `TIMESTAMP '1899-12-30 00:00:00'` to get your desired value.

In many databases (Oracle, PostgreSQL, Vertica, etc), it would be like in the query below.
In Big Query, it should be:
`TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP "1899-12-30 00:00:00", INTERVAL "Date" MINUTE) AS calculated_ts`.

And in the second query, I renamed `"Date"` to `dt`, as I shy away from using reserved words (a type designator in this case) for database objects.

```
WITH
airtable(dt,true_date) AS (
          SELECT 44493.61666666667 ,TIMESTAMP '2021-10-24T14:48:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 44522.775         ,TIMESTAMP '2021-11-22T18:36:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 44493.67916666667 ,TIMESTAMP '2021-10-24T16:18:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 44522.739583333336,TIMESTAMP '2021-11-22T17:45:00'
)
SELECT
  *
, TIMESTAMPADD(ss,CAST ((dt * 86400) AS INTEGER), TIMESTAMP '1899-12-30 00:00:00') AS derived_ts
FROM airtable;
-- out          dt         |      true_date      |     derived_ts      
-- out --------------------+---------------------+---------------------
-- out  44493.616666666670 | 2021-10-24 14:48:00 | 2021-10-24 14:48:00
-- out  44522.775000000000 | 2021-11-22 18:36:00 | 2021-11-22 18:36:00
-- out  44493.679166666670 | 2021-10-24 16:18:00 | 2021-10-24 16:18:00
-- out  44522.739583333336 | 2021-11-22 17:45:00 | 2021-11-22 17:45:00
```

Comment: Wow Great. I just wondering why is that 1899-12-30.
I also made a query to get it but it is longer than yours. 

Link: https://www.theaccountingtactics.com/2022/01/big-query-sql-date-problems-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

> Can you give a suggested query to convert it into the correct and true timestamp?

Use following expression `timestamp_seconds(cast((date - 25569) * 86400 as int))`

You can test it with the sample data in your question as in below example

```
with airtable as (
  select 44493.61666666667 date, '2021-10-24T14:48:00' expected_true_date union all 
  select 44522.775         , '2021-11-22T18:36:00' union all 
  select 44493.67916666667 , '2021-10-24T16:18:00' union all 
  select 44522.739583333336, '2021-11-22T17:45:00'
)
select *, 
  timestamp_seconds(cast((date - 25569) * 86400 as int)) calculated_true_date
from airtable
```

output

[image]